# Can't figure out how to have website point to non-storage.googleapis address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

So I'm almost finished with getting my website up.  I've created the correct bucket (www.samuraifish.com), but for some reason when I try to get the public link it's https://storage.googleapis.com/www.samuraifish.com/htdocs/index.html instead of www.samuraifish.com.  When I click on "Edit Website Configuration" I get a note that says "You can access this website at www.samuraifish.com", but when I type in www.samuraifish.com in the browser I get the following:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

How do I fix this?  I have already created my CNAME through Google Domains, so www.samuraifish.com should point to c.googleapis.com.

Thanks,
Priya

Answer (score 0):

To display a specific page when only a directory URL is requested (which is the case for a request to the domain-only `www.samuraifish.com` URL) you need to assign an index page.

From [Optional: Assigning index and error pages](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#optional_assigning_index_and_error_pages):

> An index page (also called a [webserver directory index](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index)) is the
>   file returned to visitors to your static site who request a
>   "directory". If the top level site, such as `http://www.example.com`,
>   is requested, or a missing page is requested, e.g.,
>   `http://www.example.com/directory`, the service attempts to return an
>   index page. If you haven't assigned an index page suffix, or if the
>   "directory" doesn't have an associated index page, Cloud Storage
>   returns an error page. The property that controls which file acts as
>   the index page is `MainPageSuffix`.
>
> For example, if the `MainPageSuffix` is `index.html`, Cloud Storage
>   attempts to return the object `www.example.com/index.html` when a user
>   requests `http://www.example.com`. Similarly, if there is no object
>   `www.example.com/directory`, then Cloud Storage attempts to return the
>   object `www.example.com/directory/index.html` when a user requests
>   `http://www.example.com/directory`. If there is no such object, Cloud
>   Storage returns an error page.

Comment: I've figured out my issue.  I had added an index page, but I had specified it as index.html, when my index.html (and everything else) is included in an htdocs folder.  When I look up www.samuraifish.com/htdocs/index.html, my website comes up as I expect it to, but when I make my index page htdocs/index.html, the html of my website shows up but everything else, like the styling, doesn't.  Any idea why?