# How to access Google Static Site with domain name rather than https://storage.googleapis.com/example.com/index.html

Tags: url, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket, static-site

I am setting up a static site using a domain name purchased from godaddy and a google cloud bucket. I have followed the tutorial and changed the CNAME record to c.storage.googleapis.com., however, I am unable to reach my site via the domain address. I can only view it using https://storage.googleapis.com/example.com. When I type in the domain name I get an error saying that the browser cannot find the server. How do I set up my site so that I can access it using www.example.com?

Have followed this: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website to the letter

Comment: already looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409921/cant-figure-out-how-to-have-website-point-to-non-storage-googleapis-address; it is not relevant as their domain was purchased from Google directly.

Comment: If you ping your target URL (your own domain URL) ... what IP address is returned?  Does it point to Google?  Also, what is the name of your bucket?

Comment: when I ping the purchased domain's url I get back a godaddy ip address. the name of the bucket it identical to the domain url (ex. domain = xxx.com, bucket = xxx.com, cname record is for xxx.com)

Comment: also, we did this for www.xxx.com and xxx.com (the root domain and subdomain) thinking that could be the problem, but neither gave us the desired result.

Comment: I'm no expert in this stuff and could be a million miles off base ... but my gut is saying that if we were to resolve your domain (xxx.com) then we should find that the IP returned from DNS will be that of c.storage.googleapis.com.   I seem to have some memory that it can take days for a DNS propagation to occur.  Maybe look for a tool that tests a URL resolution by asking a godaddy DNS server?

Comment: I did as you suggested and got the same IP. I really appreciate your help--I'm stumped. I've watched and read a lot of tutorials and looked at documentation from google and godaddy and I can't find an answer. This is a day's old problem so I think the propagation should have caught up by now.

Comment: What I'd suggest next is posting a screen shot of your godaddy DNS configuration.  Blur out anything you think sensitive but try and include as much info as possible.  Maybe we can spot something.

Comment: create a bucket with the subdomain name, then add a cname record that points to it --> https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#cname 
wait for 72hrs to propagate then try to access it.